# How to retrieve the tr element upon clicking a td element from typescript?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, typescript

In my html file:

```
<tbody id="tableBody">
     <tr ng-repeat="item in redirectsCtrl.csvData">
          <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.sourceURL}}</td>
          <td style="text-align:center;">{{item.redirectURL}}</td>
          <td style="text-align:center;" ng-click="redirectsCtrl.onEditButtonClick()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></td>
          <td style="text-align:center;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

In my typescript file (the angularjs controller function)

```
public onEditButtonClick() {}
```

To clarify, the edit button is basically designed so that I can edit an entry in a row of the table and as such I need access to the row's entries. So when I click the edit button I need its associated tr element, however, I can't use `$(this)` to retrieve the clicked element (and by definition its parent) in typescript because of contextual scoping.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you interested to get `item` value of particular row or what?

Comment: I want to retrieve the Element itself (the td element of the edit button upon ng-click)

Answer (score 1):

As angular is mvc framework you can manipulate on data in controller and not  view, simply:
return this line:

```
<td ng-click="redirectsCtrl.onEditButtonClick()">...</td>
```

to:

```
<td ng-click="redirectsCtrl.onEditButtonClick(item)">...</td>
```

and in your controller do your stuff:

```
 onEditButtonClick(item) {
    item.someProp = "someValue"
  }
```